# How to combine 2 datatables into 1 side by side in VB.net (for ASP.net)?

Tags: asp.net, datatable

I would like to combine these 2 datatables:

DataTable 1:

```
 A | B | C
----------
 1 | 7 | 6
 4 | 5 | 2
```

DataTable 2:

```
 A | E | F
-----------
 1 | 8 | 9
 4 | 1 | 3
```

Expected Result (New DataTable):

```
  A  |  B  |  C  | S_A | S_E | S_F
----------------------------------
  1  |  7  |  6  |  1  |  8  |  9
  4  |  5  |  2  |  4  |  1  |  3
```

Can somebody show me some sample codes for getting this done?
(Column A from both table are the keys, result column adds "S_" to the column name of 2nd table)
*result will be based on DataTable 1 in case the 2nd DataTable have no records for some rows, just show it as blank for the 2nd table

Comment: you can try with this https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/b182bf/how-to-add-two-datatable-in-single-datatable-in-C-Sharp/

Answer (score 0):

You can add columns of 2nd table into first table using AddColumn method.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/dataset-datatable-dataview/adding-columns-to-a-datatable